# Sitecore 8.0 (build 3) MVC WFFM Custom Validator not working

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

Cannot get into a custom validator I built on a Sitecore 8 MVC Web Form for Marketers form.

Here are my steps I used to build the validators:
1) I created a C# app (.NET 4.5), and build the dll for file validations.  Built, copied the .DLL to the Bin Directory.  Works fine in a Sitecore 6.6 site we have, sitecore 8.0 site it does not work.

Here is the validation code (I modified to set args.IsValid to false for testing).

```
namespace SitecoreUtilities.UploadFile
{
    public class RestrictSize : FormCustomValidator
    {
        public int MaxFileSize
        {
            get
            {
                int maxSize;
                if (int.TryParse(base.classAttributes["MaxFileSize"], out maxSize))
                {
                    return maxSize;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            set
            {
                base.classAttributes["MaxFileSize"] = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        public RestrictSize()
        {
            this.ServerValidate += this.OnSizeValidate;
        }

        private void OnSizeValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            FileUpload fileUpload = FindControl(ControlToValidate) as FileUpload;
            if (!fileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                args.IsValid=true;
                return;
            }
            args.IsValid = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength <= MaxFileSize;
            args.IsValid = false;  // TESTING to confirm getting in here
        }
    }
}
```

2) created new validator(s): 
Location: sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Validation/FileUpload/AllowedFileSize

- assembly: SitecoreUtilities
- Class: SitecoreUtilities.UploadFile.RestrictSize
- MVC Type: *blank*
- Validator Display: Dynamic
- Enable Client Script: checked
- Parameters: *empty as I put on the actual item*
- Localized Parameters: *empty*
- Inner Control: checked

3) Added Validator to the Field Types / Simple Types / File Upload Item

[image]

4) Added the file upload to the form field:

[image]

5) Saved, published.. cannot get to work on the site.

BTW, I set up a local.test.org site in IIS 7.5 on my machine and went into the project in visual studio and attached to W3Wp but it did not get into the application.

If I missed a step on this deploy please advise.

**Update 1**: Added MVC to the title
**Update 2**: Added the C# code per code difference between my code and https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/validations/walkthrough_create_and_assign_a_custom_fieldtype_validator.

Comment: Is your form a MVC form or not?

Comment: If your code works in v6, it's likely not to work in v8 as some things changed between those version in wffm... Can you check https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/validations/walkthrough_create_and_assign_a_custom_fieldtype_validator and see whether it conforms with your code and setup?

Comment: Thx Gatogordo for responding. 1) yes MVC (I updated the subject).  if inquiring as I left that field blank in the validator, I just modeled after other validators as it is empty.  2) Thanks for sending that link.  I just made some adjustments to the code, even forced args.IsValid to false, still not hitting edit.

Comment: For MVC forms you should read this: http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/05/sitecore-wffm-mvc-fileuploadfield.html It works a bit different compared to webforms..

Answer (score 2):

For WFFM MVC forms you need to work with validation attributes. I wrote blog post with an example [here](http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/05/sitecore-wffm-mvc-fileuploadfield.html). The example used is also for a file upload, so it should be relevant. It comes down to creating an attribute, inherited from `DynamicValidationBase`. You do need to create a new field as well, just to add the attributes - you don't need to write new code there.

The code in the blog is for Sitecore 8.1. There might be some small differences with 8.0.

Comment: Thx Gatogordo, this seems like the solution will work for 8.1 however I do not see Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields in the Sitecore.Forms.Mvc 8.0.0 .dll .  When I look @ the logs in Sitecore I see this message: Message: Could not load type 'Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields.FileUploadField' from assembly 'Sitecore.Forms.Mvc, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: In 8.0 they are located in `Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields`

Comment: Any idea what namespace IViewModel is in.  receiving The type or namespace name 'IViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)..  Also, if you know of the best method of finding this please share.

Comment: Use any decompiler.. I use dotPeek but there are others that will do the job as well.

Comment: IViewModel does not exist in 8.0 at first sight.. I think it's IFieldModel in that version (there were quite some naming changes)

Comment: I use ILspy for decompiler, and found what I need in the 8.1 dll's.  Regarding implementing this for 8.0 I keep running into issues and it seems best thing to do is to upgrade to 8.1 and get the custom validation modules running in that environment.

Comment: 8.1 is more stable - if you can upgrade that would be a good choice